# How to combine this 2 mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this is repeated but all the solutions I found did not work, probably because both queries are on the same table.

This is what I'm doing now.

```
$sql = $database->query("SELECT id FROM attachments WHERE user='$user_id'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$sql = $database->query("SELECT id FROM attachments WHERE member_id IN ($found_groups)");
$count += mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

$found_groups is a string that comes from a previous query

```
$sql_groups = $database->query("SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM tbl_members WHERE client_id='$client_id'");
```

And the result is then imploded

Both queries work fine. The problem is that the results are not DISTINCT and that there are 3 queries for each user, which I feel are a lot.

How could I reduce this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM attachments 
WHERE user='$user_id' OR member_id IN ($found_groups)
```

Comment: Somehow the final count for this query is different from the previous two (5 attachments total including own and those to groups the user belongs to). Even if I remove the DISTINCT part, it will only give me 3. :(

Comment: Are you sure the original results were fine? No duplicate IDs?

Comment: Attachments are either for users (there are 3 on the user I'm using for testing) or groups of users. In this case, 2 attachments are for groups where this user exists, so that makes a total of 5 available attachments.

Comment: I see... what do you get when you run this query directly: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM attachments WHERE user='$user_id' OR member_id IN ($found_groups)`?

Comment: I will not be able to run that query since member_id doesn't exist on this table. Only group id, which is a foreign key of the members table (which has 1 record for each member on each group)

Comment: My mistake, sorry. The original query is giving me 5 results. The problem is that I cannot separate the count of individual files, from those that are in groups. Can that be done by adding a different alias or result string or something to those that come from user='$user_id' and those that come from after the OR statement?

Comment: Let's put it simpler (i made a mess on that explanation). I need to count those results that come from the first part of the WHERE clase, and a separate count on those that come from the second part (the OR).

Comment: I see, then there's no way to do it without two queries (even within a same query) or joins... Both way would make a similar load on the database, so you shouldn't bother much with that.

Comment: I see. So it's not about how many queries you make, but how heavy they are? I mean, if I make 200 very simple queries (despite the shared hosting hourly limit on how many I make) it will not be a problem? Thanks for your help again!!

Comment: Ah, in case you have that limit, you can still use my code, order them by `user_id` and then use php to traverse through the results, increasing counter. Once `user_id` becomes NULL (or false, or whatever you define it), you start a new counter for group_id part. That way you'll technically do only one query and let php do the double counter stuff.

Comment: p.s. you don't even have to order by user_id - you can just check if user_id is NULL/false in a row, and if so, increase the group counter, and if not, increase the single user counter.

Comment: Oh, that is an amazing solution! I need to add 2 more fields to the SELECT clause then (user_id and group_id) and on the fetch_array check which one is not empty. Thanks!! Less code = more joy!